# make DIV take all lower space

Tags: html, css

Let's say for example:

```
<header>Hello</header>
<div role="main">Body</div>
<footer>&copy;</footer>

header {
    height:20px;
    background: #edf1f5;
}
div {
    background:#ddd;
    padding:20px;
}
footer {
    background: #e4e8ec;
}​
```

How do you make `footer` take up all the remaining space? I am not aiming to have a sticky footer here, I just want the footer to fill up the space.

---

Here's a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XF3E7/

Comment: you want the visual effect or what? is it possible to achieve this by filling `<body>` with the same color?

Comment: nope not the visual effect, the footer needs to stretch till the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @JackSpairow why not a visual effect? Can you explain that to us? There's no reason for that in your current design.

Comment: but i think this is not the exact of answer of the question guys.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I was able to answer my own question:

http://jsfiddle.net/XF3E7/14/

Answer (score 3):

I've always used a work around for this. If you make the body background colour the same as the footer it creates the illusion of it extending down the page. http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/q3xzh/1/

```
header {
height:20px;
background: #edf1f5;
}
div {
background:#ddd;
padding:20px;
}
footer {
background: #e4e8ec;
}
body {background:#e4e8ec;}
```

Comment: if i will change the footer background color in your code than what will happen did you try it....

Comment: hey @Ollie spose i have diffrent color of body and footer as like this  http://jsfiddle.net/q3xzh/2/

Comment: Then you just change it to whatever colour you need. http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/nqGCb/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/XF3E7/5/

But no scrolling heh? It's not possible without javascript or using tables.

I'd indeed suggest using a background color as @Ollie said.

Comment: I don't think so... setting `footer{height:100%}` is a bad idea and using tables is also a bad idea. Tableless Web Design was invented 2002 already.

Comment: Using tables is a bad idea, which is why I suggest to use @Ollie's solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to play with the css

http://jsfiddle.net/XF3E7/10/

Comment: The problem with this is the additional height it adds, making it scrollable.

Comment: The problem with your problem is that it was not specified. you wanted the footer to take up the rest of the body but you don't wan the scroller to appear try fixing it with overflow property OR use javascript to figure out window height onload event and on resize event and fix the height then?